# cant parse std object class

Tags: php, json, twitter

I am using a Twitter API to parse std object class. this is what my output looks like. I've been using json_decode and json_encode, but I keep getting errors. How do I access the elements?

```
stdClass Object ( [statuses] => Array ( ) [search_metadata] => stdClass Object ( [completed_in] => 0.006 [max_id] => 443759527804944385 [max_id_str] => 443759527804944385 [query] => hello+josh [refresh_url] => ?since_id=443759527804944385&q=hello%20josh&include_entities=1 [count] => 15 [since_id] => 0 [since_id_str] => 0 ) )
```

Comment: "*Twitter API to parse std object class.*" -- Are you sure? Maybe you meant "*I'm trying to parse an object that's returned by Twitter API*"? Please edit your question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You use `->` to access object properties, and `[]` to access array elements. So for instance it would be:

```
$object->statuses['search_metadata']->completed_in
```